# Flex 4 - Current Items in Viewport of a List?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, list

I have provided an ArrayCollection to a List, works fine, scroll and sweet.

I am able to access the carretIndex (though not necessarily the ones in view) by 
`list.caretIndex`

Is it possible to access the list of **items currently visible** in the List.

What I am curious to know, is how can I can access (read) the first (*or any of the*) item in a given View port of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Florian, 
That gave me a direction in searching in the DataGroup for the currently in view, Turns out Adobe has the perfect method for this basic problem: 
`scroller.dataGroup.getItemIndicesInView()` 
and this returns you an Vector.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621716/how-to-get-the-visible-items-on-a-spark-list-with-virtual-layout) or [this](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/151805)